# Sharepoint/Sharepoint Online: How can I create ChangeToken without using MSFT libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, changelog

I'm looking for a way to create SP.CHANETOKEN without using MSFT Sharepoint libraries (dlls) 
Suppose I have the following information available. How can I use the Site ID, and the Time to obtain a changetoken value?

> {u'WebId': u'efb506c9-761e-4178-ac03-4903a358e2a6', u'ListId':
>   u'799bdaf0-5e11-40c6-a933-0d335025995f',  u'SiteId':
>   u'190b1248-8c70-4279-a638-842065663333', u'Time':
>   u'2016-09-15T09:01:19Z'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changetoken is a semicolon delimited string, and takes the following parameters in the order listed:

- Version number.
- The change scope (0 - Content Database, 1 - site collection, 2 - site, 3 - list).
- GUID of the item the scope applies to (for example, GUID of the list). In my case it was **efb506c9-761e-4178-ac03-4903a358e2a6** because I was trying to get changes on the WEB level.
- Time (in UTC) from when changes occurred. This one is a bit tricky, you'll need to provide the ticks count since [.NET minvalue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Change item on the ChangeToken (you may provide a default value for this > -1)

Sample change token

> 1;2;efb506c9-761e-4178-ac03-4903a358e2a6;636100287540000000;-1

Following links explain it with sample code.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/query-sharepoint-change-log-with-changequery-and-changeToken.md

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/query-sharepoint-change-log-with-changequery-and-changetoken

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer.